# JQuery simple onClick function doesn't work (calculator)

Tags: jquery, calculator

I want to calculate euro to dollar.

```js
$("#ber").on("click"function() {
  var zahl = $("#auswahl").val();
  var erg = zahl * 1.15;

  $("#erg").text(erg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deep-purple">
  <button class="btn" id="ber">Berechnen</button>
  <label style="font-size: 2em; margin-left: 1em;" for="berechnen" id="erg">
            Ergebnis
        </label>
  <input id="auswahl" class="input-box" type="text">
</div>
```

But the console says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

What could be the problem?

Comment: commam missing: `.on("click", function(){`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ber").on("click" function(){
//                  ^ missing comma
```

Comment: pls add some explanation code only answers are bit confusing to others

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram the comment = the necessary info, hence I voted to close and downvoted - it's a typo issue which should be flagged and closed

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a `comma ','` on your `on()` function. ([Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

You can use [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demo your code and observe errors more accurate.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p7j4t6rd/) is your code in JS Fiddle. When you clicked `Tidy` button site will tidy your code and you can see errors more clearly.

Hope it helps